# ¿Como solucionar este error de jade?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, jade

Recién estoy iniciando en nodeJS y estoy usando JADE como *view engine*, solo estoy haciendo pruebas, nada extraordinario, y sin embargo lanza el siguiente error:

```
C:\Users\Familia\Documents\node\expres\node_modules\promise\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Familia\Documents\node\expres\node_modules\jstransformer\index.js:5:15)
```

Mi código es el siguiente **app.js**:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.get("/",(req, res)=>{
    res.render("index");
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Y este es el **index.jade**:

```
html
    head
        title "mi primera página con jade"
    body
        h1 "Hola Mundo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un par de detalles acerca de tu código

1. jade es un motor de plantillas que esta descontinuado y en un futuro cercano deberías probar Pug que es la versión que nació
2. Te hace falta declarar la variable que contendrá el path (esta se necesita para que el llamado a tus archivos se haga como ruta absoluta sin importar si cambiar el nombre de la carpeta)
3. No vi que hayas instalado jade, por lo cual primero debes hacer `npm i -S jade`
4. Declara una variable jade que contenga el llamado al módulo jade
5. En el res.render agrega el path.join

Mira este código para tu archivo .js

```
var express = require("express");
var jade = require("jade")
var path    = require("path");

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade')

app.get("/", function(req, res){
     res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/index'));
}).listen(8080);
```

Para tu archivo Jade, te dejo este ejemplo, donde como puedes notar esta incpmpleta tu declaración de las etiquetas y considerando que jade hace un compilado de las mismas para luego mostrar un HTML pues por eso también da error

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
  body
    h1 Jade 
      p.
        Hola a Todos
```

> Si por ejemplo copias y pegas este código asi tal cual, desde la
>   consola a nivel de la carpeta que contiene a tu proyecto, debes hacer un npm install para que ejecute e instale las
>   dependencias que te hagan falta

Al respecto del motor de plantillas PUg te dejo 2 enlaces; el primero es para ver su proceso de descarga e instalación

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug

El segundo es para que veas desde su sitio oficial como se usa

https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Comment: Gracias por responder, de todos modos lo que solucione fue eliminar los modulos de express y de jade y volverlo a instalarlos, voy a revisar lo de PUG gracias por la recomendacion, y tomare bastante en cuenta lo que me falto en el documento HTML para los futuras plantillas. Gracias!